# Updated VS Code and now all my Ubuntu files are read-only

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I did an update of VS Code.
After the update the first thing I noticed was that I could no longer run npm run start-dev on one of my projects. It would give me EROFS: read-only file system. (additionally I cannot run commands to push my code up to Git Hub)

I thought to try deleting the node_modules and reinstalling them and it wouldn't let me delete them due to the read-only file system as well.

I've tried many things in looking through stack overflow such as:
uninstalling and reinstalling the WSL extension for vscode,
checking to see what this command (npm root -g) returns, it does not return -npm,
tried the command sudo fsck -f /dev/sdc
tried manually changing the permissions on files from read-only to r+w using chmod and sudo commands

I expected the files to no longer be read only so that I could run npm commands in WSL VS Code again.

I'm completely at a loss.

Here is a screen shot of my most recent error code because now after all of the things I've tried, I cannot even get a WSL window of VS Code to open at all.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi8yA.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0oaV.png)

Comment: Hi, please avoid imgs of code/errors...  read this: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417)

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo e2fsck /dev/sdc -y
```

Worked to fix my issue